# The use of the construction "one's +gerund +..." as subject

Tags: gerund-clauses

Can I use the phrase

> "My being neat and quiet"

as a subject of the sentence?

For example,

> ***My being neat and quiet*** seems something they appreciate.

Comment: Sure. But you can't "seem" things, so write "My being neat and quiet *seems like* (or *seems to be*) something they appreciate."

Comment: @user3169 [It seems you are incorrect about that.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seem)

Comment: seem should be followed by adjective. It's a linking verb. however, it could be: `seem that ..., seem to, seem to be`

Comment: @user3169, what is the head-word of "My being neat and quiet" ? It must be a noun, right?

Comment: @HermanNz "my being neat and quiet" is a clause, with explicit subject, verb and object of its own.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast with other languages a gerund is a verbal that ends in -ing and functions as a noun.

> The term verbal indicates that a gerund, like the other two kinds of verbals, is based on a verb and therefore expresses action or a state of being. However, since a gerund functions as a noun, it occupies some positions in a sentence that a noun ordinarily would, for example: subject, direct object, subject complement, and object of preposition.
>
> Gerund as subject:
>
> •  Traveling might satisfy your desire for new experiences. (Traveling is the gerund.)
>
> •  The study abroad program might satisfy your desire for new experiences. (The gerund has been removed.)
>
> Gerund as direct object:
>
> •  They do not appreciate my singing. (The gerund is singing.)
>
> •  They do not appreciate my assistance. (The gerund has been removed)
>
> -OWl Purdue

When the gerund functions as a subject or object it may take the possessive pronoun.

So, in this case “My being neat and quiet” functions as the subject.

Answer (score 1):

If a gerund has a determiner in front of it (possessive pronouns and articles are determiners), or an object pronoun in front it, it does not change the rules where gerunds are used.

> Walking to the park made me tired.
>
> My walking to the park made me tired.
>
> The walking to the park made me tired.

Answer (score 1):

> My being neat and quiet seems something they appreciate.

This is a correct sentence.

The complement (subject) of this sentence is a clause (Gerund-Participle clause) - *"my being neat and clean"*. The VP - *seems something* - is also correct; it's verb + complement (Object). Then the object is being modified by a non-wh relative clause - *"they appreciate ___"*.

The gap in the relative clause (I denoted it with "___") is anaphorically linked to the object of the main clause - *something*. So *something* fills the gap of the relative clause - *they appreciate _something_*.

Comment: No, it's not a correct sentence. "seems like something they appreciate" would be correct.

Comment: @verbose I agree that the alternative you suggested is far more common, but the sentence OP asked is also correct as is.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "correct", I guess.

Comment: @verbose I believe whether to add *to be* (or *like*) after *seem* is decided by the type of Predicative Complement present after *seem*. If it's Specifying there has to be a *to be* (Or *like*) after *seem*. It's not the case here. The PC - *something* - is not specifying anything here.

Comment: yes, it is. It's specifying "something they appreciate." It's not merely an unspecified "something".

Comment: @verbose but it's a property, and not an identity. So it's Ascriptive, not Specifying.

Comment: No, it's specifying. On what basis are you saying it's ascriptive? "Something they appreciate" is not an adjectival clause. It is an identity.

Comment: @verbose thinking about it for some more time I think it can be analyzed by both ways. So adding **to be** here is optional.

Comment: In no way can "something they appreciate" be adjectival. And if you want to discuss it further, please move to chat; but you'd be doing the OP a favor by editing your answer to remove the assertion that the sentence is correct.

Comment: @verbose it's not adjectival. It's a NP.

Comment: Exactly. That's what makes it specifying and not ascriptive.

Comment: @verbose no not like that. What I mean is the PC - *something* - can be thought of a property that is ascribed to the subject. Or it can be a specifying entity. So it's ambiguous. Either Ascriptive or specifying complement.

Comment: Your analysis does not convince. I don't see how an entity can be "thought of as" a property of another entity. And in the OP's sentence, leaving out "like" is unambiguously wrong. However, since you're determined to defend your stance, I'm done with this discussion.

Comment: @verbose *he is my friend* the predicative complement is *my friend*, a NP. It can be a property of the subject, or it can specify the subject, can distinguish him from other people. The PC here is ambiguous.

Comment: @verbose not determined. I just like healthy discussion. I might be completely wrong too.

Comment: @verbose Would you think *She seems a lady of many talents* is ungrammatical as well? What about this by *I thought it a liberty; but still, as he seemed a gentleman, I told him he might come*, John Keats?